# Java.RestAssured.параметры Get запроса не передаются

Tags: java, rest-assured

Есть код:

```
public class rest_GetUserClaims {
    @Test
    public void GetUserClaims() throws JsonException {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://ss.sssss.ru:8505";
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = RestAssured.given()
                    .when()
                        .queryParam("sessionid", "8998650247557394755").queryParam("messageid", "d2b906c5-ab6c-4462-98ec-b76a0055b5bd").queryParam("correlationid", "d2b906c5-ab6c-4462-98ec-b76a0055b5bd").queryParam("systemid", "android")
                    .get("/mobile/abcde/getUserAbcde");}

         catch (Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
            System.out.println("Response :" + response.asString());
            System.out.println("Status Code :" + response.getStatusCode());

        }}
```

Подскажите, почему параметры запроса не передаются у меня?

> Response :{"response":{"systemId":null,"messageId":null,"correlationId":null,"sessionId":null,"absdes":{"abcde":[]

Answer (score 0):

Параметры запроса, формат контента и прочее, что относится в формированию запроса, пишется после `given()` и до `then()`. В вашем случае код будет выглядеть так:

```
RestAssured
    .given()
        .queryParam("sessionid", "8998650247557394755")
        .queryParam("messageid", "d2b906c5-ab6c-4462-98ec-b76a0055b5bd")
        .queryParam("correlationid", "d2b906c5-ab6c-4462-98ec-b76a0055b5bd")
        .queryParam("systemid", "android")
    .when()
        .get("/mobile/abcde/getUserAbcde");
```

[JavaDoc](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.1.1/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#given--) метода `given()`